# long term behavior of solution to a first order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, nonlinear-dynamics, bifurcation

Consider the following system of first order nonlinear autonomous ODEs (derivatives are taken with respect to $t$):
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = -2xy^2+1 \\
\dot{y} = -2x^2y+1 \\
x(0) = x_0,\;y(0)=y_0
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that

1. if initial condition satisfies $x_0=y_0$, then $x(t)=y(t)$ for all $t\geq 0$ and $x(t)\to 1/\sqrt[3]{2}$ as $t\to\infty$.
2. if $x_0\ne y_0$, then the solution is unbounded, i.e., $|x(t)|+|y(t)|\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$.

---

For (1), my intuition is that if $x_0=y_0$, then $\dot{x}=-2x^3+1$ and $\dot{y}=-2y^3+1$, i.e., $x$ and $y$ are decoupled. However, I don't know how to argue it rigorously. If this is indeed true, then it is easy because this system has only one equilibrium, i.e., $x^*=1/\sqrt[3]{2}$, and if $x(t)>x^*$, $\dot{x}<0$, so $x(t)$ is decreasing. Similarly, if $x(t)<x^*$, $\dot{x}>0$, so $x(t)$ is increasing.

---

For (2), I have no idea how to approach. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: What have you tried -- this looks like homework or an exercise.

Comment: @Bey No, this is not homework or exercise. My question is that I don't know any methods that I could have a try. Would you please give at least some hint?

Comment: What is this for then?

Comment: @Bey This is a small intermediate step of a project. Anyway, I have added what I tried.

Comment: +1 Thanks! That is good enough :) The issue is we have a lot of people trying to get us to do their homework without even trying, hence the ask to show efforts to date.

Comment: @Bey I totally understand that. Thanks!

Comment: Hint.

Subtracting 

$$
\cases{
x x'=-\frac 12 x^2y^2+x\\
y y'=-\frac 12 x^2 y^2+y
}
$$

$$
\frac 12((x+y)(x-y))'=x-y
$$

Comment: Or also $\frac 12(x^2)'-x = \frac 12(y^2)'-y$

Comment: @Cesareo Thanks for the hint. Is this for part (1) or (2)? I could obtain this relation but what does this relation imply?

Comment: With this last expression, if $x_0 = y_0$ then $x = y$.

Comment: @Cesareo I am sorry, but I still don't get why $x_0=y_0$ implies $x=y$ with $(x^2)'-x=(y^2)'-y$. How do you argue this? Shall I integrate on both sides? or shall I use some continuous version of mathematical induction?

Comment: @Cesareo If $x_0=y_0$, then with the last expression, we will have $x'(0)=y'(0)$, but we still don't know $x'(t)=y'(t)$ or $x(t)=y(t)$ right? I think the missing part is some version of induction like in discrete case, but I don't know how to make it rigorous.

Comment: If not $|x|+|y|\to\infty$, then the (forward) solution stays bounded. It has thus to converge to a stationary point. However, the only stationary point is the point on the diagonal from 1), it is a saddle point and the stable manifold is the diagonal.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks! Does it guarantees no other place can be on the stable manifold?

Comment: Yes, with a regular Jacobian there are only two curves that are asymptotic to the eigen-direction of the negative eigenvalue. But I forgot to mention that you also need to exclude stable limit cycles. But these demand a source inside, which is not present for this system.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Which two curves in this case? I only know one of them is $x=y$.